# How can I ensure that a div without content will get the height of the parent div?

Tags: css, responsive-design, bourbon, neat

i am trying to create to `divs` width the outer container set to `1000px` and the inner left and right container to `50%` each.
Now i have used this code

```
.leftNav {
    @include span-columns( 5 of 10);
    background-color:silver;
    color:white;
}

.rightNav {
    @include span-columns( 5 of 10);
    background-color:silver;
    color:white;
}
```

**Now somehow if i don't put anything on left `nav` the right `nav` takes full 100% width.**
How can i set the `leftnav` or `rightnav` to maintain at least 50% width even if they are empty?
thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This "issue" doesn't come from Neat, but from CSS itself. To be shown, an empty element require to have a height.You can use one of the following tricks:

- Put `&nbsp;` in your div
- Set a `height` on your div
- Set a `padding` on your div

Here's another trick I like, if you're not using the `:after` pseudo-element on these div:

```
.leftNav:after,
.rightNav:after {
    content: '.'; // dot will force its parent to have a height
    opacity: 0;   // dot is hidden
}
```

Comment: The `&nbsp;` did the trick for me. I wanted an empty div to be the same height as when it wasn't empty.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [css tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display).

Setting `display:table-cell` on both the left and right divs will ensure that each one gets equal height (ie the height of the greater of the two)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hb9f96w3/1/)**

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.left {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  background: silver;
}
.right {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
.leftNav:after,
.rightNav:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Then you don't have to deal with any dots which could be confusing to someone else looking at your code.